# Converting Shell Output to json

Tags: json, shell, octave

I want to convert the output of octave execution in shell to json format.

For example if I execute

```
$ octave --silent --eval 'a=[1,3],b=2'
```

I get

```
a =

   1   3

b =  2
```

I want the output to be formatted to a json string as in

```
"{'a':[1,3], 'b':2}"
```

How do I achieve this, It would be great if it is in node/js, but anthing is fine. I am looking for any existing solutions to rather than writing my own logic for parsing it. Need suggestion.

Comment: perhaps http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ can be of help

Comment: I for myself found that when it comes to JSON it's kind of the end of what you want to do with bash. Other languages like Ruby & Python seem far more suitable for that.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if any such package exists. Its easy to write your own rather thank waiting to find one.